# How to search and get the values in a database using spring-mvc?

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc, jsp, controller

I've created a login form where I can save, update and search student details. I've completed the save and update function and I'm struggling to complete the function of the save button. I could get the searched values to the consol but not to the JSP page.

The JSP page contains three buttons with separate javascript functions for create, update and search student details.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/auths", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void search(
            @RequestParam(value="Id") long studentid,
            @RequestParam(value="Name") String name,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest
            ){

        StudentCoursesSisi objct=dobj.find(studentid);
        if(objct != null){
            System.out.println(objct.getStudentName());
            model.addAttribute("studentName",objct.getStudentName());

        }


    }
```

JSP

```
<form id = "frmStudent" onsubmit="return false;">
                        <div class="panel-body">                            
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group" >
                                <!--  Student Id -->
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label customlabel">Student Id</label>

                                <!-- Input Item -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group " >
                                        <!-- Input type -->
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control reset" id="txtStudentId"
                                            name="studentId" value="${studentId}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ./Input Item -->
                                <!-- ./student id -->                                     
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style = "margin-top : 15px;">
                                <!--  Student Name -->
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label customlabel">Student Name</label>

                                <!-- Input Item -->
                                <div class="col-md-8">                                   
                                    <!-- Input type -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control reset" id="txtStudentName"
                                        name="studentName" value="${studentName}">                                   
                                </div>
                                <!-- ./Input Item -->
                                <!-- ./student id -->                                     
                            </div>



                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style = "margin-top : 15px;">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label customlabel">Gender</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6" >
                                    <input type="radio" class="  large" id="optMale"
                                        style="margin-top: 8px;" name="gender" value="M">
                                        Male &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                     <input type="radio" class="    large"
                                        id="optFemale" style="margin-top: 8px;"
                                        name="gender" value="F"> Female
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            </div>





                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group" style = "margin-top : 15px;">
                                <!--  Centre Status -->
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label customlabel">Language</label>

                                <!-- Input Item -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <kendo:dropDownList id="lan" name="language" dataTextField="text"
                                        dataValueField="value" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <kendo:dataSource data="${languageList}">   
                                        <select id="dropdown">
                                            <option>Sinhala</option>
                                            <option>English</option>
                                            <option>Tamil</option>
                                        </select>                                        
                                        </kendo:dataSource>
                                    </kendo:dropDownList>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ./Input Item -->
                                <!-- ./Centre Status -->

                                <div class = "col-md-7">
                                    <p class="text-danger col-md-4 reset" id="createdUser" style = "padding-top: 4px;"></p>
                                    <p class="text-danger col-md-8 reset" id="createdDate" style = "padding-top: 4px;"></p> 
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button class = "btn btn-default" title = "Clear Form" name = "clear" id = "btnClear" type = "reset" >
                                <i class = "fa fa-eraser"></i> Clear
                            </button>                    

                            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" title="Save Record" name="save" id="btnSave" type="button" onclick="authUser()" >
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> &nbsp; Save Me 
                            </button>   

                            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" title="Save Record" name="save" id="btnSave" type="button" onclick="authUserUpdate()" >
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> &nbsp; Update
                            </button>

                            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" title="Save Record" name="save" id="btnSave" type="button" onclick="authUsersearch()" >
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> &nbsp; Search
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Student Courses</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "panel-body" style = "padding: 0px;">
                        <kendo:grid name = "courseDetails" autoBind = "true" selectable = "true" editable = "true" pageable = "true" sortable= "false" columnMenu="true" >                      

                            <kendo:grid-columns>
                                <kendo:grid-column title = "Course Code" field = "courseCode" />
                                <kendo:grid-column title = "Course Name" field = "courseName" />
                                <kendo:grid-column title = "Created User" field = "createdUser" />
                                <kendo:grid-column title = "Created Date" field = "createdDate" format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />
                            </kendo:grid-columns>

                            <kendo:dataSource pageSize="2" data= "data" serverPaging="true"serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="true" serverGrouping="true">
                                <kendo:dataSource-transport>
                                    <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url = "${readUrl}" type="post" dataType="json" contentType="application/json"/>
                                    <kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
                                        <script>
                                            function parameterMap(options, type) {
                                                return JSON.stringify(options);
                                            }
                                        </script>
                                    </kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
                                </kendo:dataSource-transport>

                                <kendo:dataSource-schema data="data" total="total">
                                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                                            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name = "createdDate" type="date">
                                                <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-parse>
                                                    <script>
                                                        function parseDate(e){
                                                            if (e != null)
                                                                return kendo.parseDate(new Date(e), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
                                                        }   
                                                    </script>
                                                </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-parse>
                                            </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                                        </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>

                                </kendo:dataSource-schema>
                            </kendo:dataSource>
                        </kendo:grid>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END YOUR CONTENT -->

        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT FRAME BODY -->

    </div>
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT FRAME -->

</div>
<!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->

<kendo:notification name="saveNotification" autoHideAfter="10000">
    <kendo:notification-position pinned="true" right="10" top="85" />
</kendo:notification>

<script>
    var popupNotification = $("#saveNotification").kendoNotification({
        position : {
            pinned : true,
            top : 85,
            left : null,
            bottom : null,
            right : 20
        }
    }).data("kendoNotification");

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList();

    });

    function authUser(){
          $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : 'student/auth',
           dataType : "json",
           data : {
            Name : $('#txtStudentName').val(),
            StudentId : $('#txtStudentId').val(),
            Rad : $("input[name='gender']:checked").val(),
            stdlanguage : $("#lan").val(), 
           },
           success : function(response) {

            if(response === success){     
             popupNotification.show('success');
            console.log(response);
             }else{
              popupNotification.show('error');
              }
           },
          });

        }
    function authUserUpdate(){
          $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : 'student/authup',
           dataType : "json",
           data : {
            StudentId : $('#txtStudentId').val(),   
            Name : $('#txtStudentName').val(),
            Rad : $("input[name='gender']:checked").val(),
            stdlanguage : $("#lan").val(), 
           },
           success : function(response) {

            if(response === success){     
             popupNotification.show('success');
            console.log(response);
             }else{
              popupNotification.show('error');
              }
           },
          });

        }
    function authUsersearch(){
          $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : 'student/auths',
           dataType : "json",
           data : {
            Id : $('#txtStudentId').val(),
            Name : $('#txtStudentName').val(),
           },
           success : function(response) {

            if(response === success){     
             popupNotification.show('success');
            console.log(response);
             }else{
              popupNotification.show('error');
              }
           },
          });

        }
```

Comment: The `@ResponseBody` annotation means you are simply returning the String 'student' in the response. What is it you want to do. Forward to student.jsp or send Json?

Comment: That was a mistake I made, i wanted to forward it to student.jsp  @Alan Hay